# Ho to delay the default browser scroll on element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I'm building the following component using JS / SCSS but I can't achieve one thing, and I googled it but got no results. As you can see in the picture below the images are being delayed on scroll, they start to animate only after the text on right scrolled a bit, there is a delay of `300ms`.

Is there a way to delay the scroll behaviour or change the scroll speed of elements in JS?

[image]

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @MauriceNino yes it did, sorry I forgot to accept your answer, will do it now :)

Comment: No problem, was just curious :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `absolute` or `relative` placed div with a transition on the `top` property and a [transition delay](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp).

The top could be set dynamically in your `onscroll` handler, with use of [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop).

Check the snippet below or check out [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PrxZZo) for a better example.

```js
$("#container").scroll(function(){
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  $("#box").css({"top":(scrollTop+50)+"px"});
  $("#box2").css({"top":(scrollTop+70)+"px"});
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  
}

#box {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: top .2s;
}
#box2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: top .2s;
  transition-delay: .05s;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
  <div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut malesuada leo eget nisl euismod vestibulum. Proin nulla urna, ornare non erat vitae, mattis ultrices urna. Etiam elementum, tortor id lacinia mollis, risus odio accumsan ex, eu egestas nisi lacus at purus. Cras vitae orci condimentum, dictum ante nec, laoreet nunc. Cras ut tristique libero. Pellentesque tempus feugiat elit non imperdiet. Cras ac gravida enim, nec pharetra sem. Maecenas luctus leo id quam sodales, sit amet scelerisque sapien efficitur. Pellentesque aliquet fermentum molestie. Praesent a lacinia tellus. Vivamus ut rutrum ex. Pellentesque dapibus magna a mauris facilisis tincidunt. Phasellus vulputate eros ac ultrices lacinia. Mauris sed eleifend enim. Sed eu ultrices nisi.

Sed eget porttitor purus. Praesent quis commodo dolor. Morbi vitae egestas magna. Quisque eu pellentesque velit. Cras eu arcu in tortor bibendum laoreet. Quisque sed turpis risus. Vestibulum efficitur urna malesuada diam dictum, at viverra leo finibus. Duis dignissim justo sem, et euismod nisi aliquam at. Fusce pretium lacus a pretium pulvinar. Aliquam ligula nisl, sodales vel aliquet at, malesuada ac nulla. Nam lorem leo, fermentum nec volutpat id, tincidunt ac diam. Phasellus at congue ligula. Aliquam nibh mi, tempor eu auctor id, sollicitudin eu ante. Donec quis nunc molestie, pretium turpis quis, venenatis arcu.

Quisque quis auctor odio. Maecenas ullamcorper ultricies elementum. Nam sed accumsan turpis. Suspendisse viverra at augue vel lacinia. Nulla eu magna in nisl dapibus sollicitudin ut in sem. Fusce et orci nibh. Suspendisse blandit, erat non pretium condimentum, felis justo hendrerit nisi, quis lacinia eros orci a nibh. Aenean nisl mi, convallis sed convallis vitae, posuere non nunc. Quisque condimentum lorem ut urna tristique hendrerit. Cras suscipit placerat consectetur. Nullam ut iaculis lectus. Suspendisse ultrices sem urna, sit amet efficitur mi eleifend rutrum. Curabitur magna nisi, mollis quis lorem maximus, luctus pretium elit. Nunc commodo tortor sed justo condimentum ultrices. Nullam at ante sit amet leo ullamcorper fringilla. Duis ac purus at mauris fermentum pulvinar.

Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur turpis sapien, semper id nisi at, volutpat aliquam nisi. Quisque nec porttitor odio. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus suscipit ullamcorper lacus. Mauris lobortis luctus dignissim. Suspendisse non pharetra tortor, ut convallis nibh. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce malesuada, turpis nec ultrices tempor, lorem ex fringilla nunc, et efficitur lacus nisl quis nunc. Ut vestibulum elit est, id volutpat libero porttitor in. Mauris sed ante commodo, tristique quam in, molestie mauris. Duis eget porta magna, vitae fermentum ligula. Donec a dapibus nibh, in placerat metus. Donec vulputate metus vitae sapien facilisis pharetra. Nullam dui justo, maximus vel volutpat a, sodales id ligula.

Integer finibus lacus leo, eu semper tellus maximus lobortis. Nulla facilisi. Etiam lobortis interdum quam, non venenatis ligula luctus non. In laoreet, tellus at hendrerit tempus, dolor ex egestas est, in hendrerit libero nulla sit amet est. Vestibulum sem lorem, aliquam in lacus in, rutrum vulputate turpis. Morbi placerat tortor vel scelerisque auctor. Nunc in velit laoreet, egestas ante vitae, faucibus enim. Nam iaculis eros eu efficitur pharetra. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec sagittis porttitor feugiat. In nibh diam, imperdiet non dapibus sed, dapibus vitae urna. Mauris blandit tincidunt neque non gravida. Curabitur vel lectus nec lectus ullamcorper pretium at dapibus felis. Nulla fermentum, dui et sagittis facilisis, ante mi dignissim quam, non auctor nisl ante vitae mi. In vestibulum, ante vitae tempus ultrices, enim risus tristique nisi, eu aliquet augue nulla eu magna. Fusce volutpat augue sit amet felis blandit aliquam.

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it it's still not the same behaviour. The delay works, but the images still scroll on top with the text and after 300ms they animation is triggered. But in the gif I posted you can see that the images are somehow static for 300ms.

Comment: Elements with a `position` value of `fixed` will remain in the same place (defined by left/top/right/bottom properties) relative to the view rather than the scroll position. So perhaps you want to use a fixed position, and then in the scroll handler, in a timeout change the `top` property. Using a CSS transition might help sell the effect even more.

Comment: @Radu033 check the snippet.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk That makes no sense. Fixed is always realtive to viewport. If you change that top value, it will move out of screen.

Comment: @MauriceNino What? I'm saying you can change the top value to move it down relative to the viewport to simulate the element scrolling at a different rate than the actual scroll that's happening. Changing the top value may move it offscreen, if you use a large value, but smaller values can just move it down/up on the screen.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk And thats where you are wrong. The element in the video of the Question always stays in the middle, but has a small delay in its movement. If you set it to position fixed and change its top value, it will change its position on the viewport. You need to set the element at position relative to the container of the element that is scrolled and change its top value according to the current scroll position. (Check the snippet I posted). If you still think different, feel free to post a snippet to show me.